# percent character not working in html

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a method that makes a row which has an image in it for me
my code:

```
function makeRow($name,...){
    $r = '';
    $r .= "<img src=img/mamet.jpg style=padding:3px width=100% height=100% >";
    return $r;
}
```

but you see that little "%" after width and height ?

it's not working :(
it seems that PHP double quotes and single quotes have problem with this character : %(percent)
what should i do ?
i even tried these:

```
\%
\\%
"%"
'%'
```

but still not working:(

Comment: try this;  `$r .= "<img src=img/mamet.jpg style='padding:3px; width=100% ;height=100%' >";`

Comment: @AwladLiton — err. No. That's invalid CSS.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/ would be a good start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS rules should be specified using the `:` assignment operator, not the `=` operator. You also are missing the `;` EOL literal.

Try the following:

```
function makeRow($name,...)
{
    return '<img src="img/mamet.jpg" style="padding:3px; width:100%; height:100%" />';
}
```

Comment: He is using the width and height **attributes**, not CSS **properties**, so you are completely incorrect in saying that they should be `specified using the ':' assignment operator`.

Comment: @NobleUplift Not quite. They're inside the `style` attribute... Also, if you read my answer, I said that *CSS rules should be specified using the `:` assignment operator*. Nowhere did I say that HTML attributes should be...

Comment: I suppose I should have used the entire quote, because you did say it: `the ':' assignment operator, not the '=' operator`. Were you not referring to `width=100% height=100%`, which are HTML attributes?

Comment: No. I was referring to the CSS properties of the same name, hence why I said *CSS rules*,  not HTML attributes...

Comment: But my point is that the OP was using HTML attributes, so telling the OP that it was incorrect to use those attributes, is incorrect. Rather, it is incorrect for the OP to use percentages in the width and height attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the OP actually wanted to use attributes instead of CSS properties:

```
function makeRow($name,...){
    $r = '';
    $r .= '<img src="img/mamet.jpg" style="padding:3px;" width="100%" height="100%" >';
    return $r;
}
```

The reason this will not work is because [it is no longer in the HTML spec](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp). You cannot use percents in the width and height attributes for HTML 5.

Instead, place them in your style:

```
style="padding:3px; width:100%; height:100%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
function imageTag($src, $attr=array(), $style=array()){
    $img_tag = '<img src="'.$src.'"';
    // check if atributes array is not empty
    if(count($attr)){
       foreach($attr as $name => $value)
          $img_tag .= ' ' . $name . '="' . $value . '";';
    }
    // check if style array is not empty
    if(count($style)){
       $img_tag .= ' style="'; 
       foreach($style as $name => $value)
          $img_tag .= $name . ':' . $value . ';';
       $img_tag .= '"'; 
    } 

    $img_tag .= ' />';
    return $img_tag;
}
```

Function usage:

```
echo imageTag('images/image.jpg',array('title' => 'Image title', 'alt' => 'image_alt'), array('height' => '100%', 'width' => '100%', 'padding' => '5px'));
```